# Latitude Longitude JSON C# Serialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I would like to take this class and convert it to JSON.

```
public class Location
{
  public string city {get; set;}
  public double population {get; set;}
  public double Latitude {get; set;}
  public double Longitude {get; set;}
}
```

In this format by [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
[
  {  
"city ": "Atlanta, GA",
"Value": 520,
    "Location": [
      42.7,
      23.33
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit strange format for this class. So try:

```
public class Location
{
    [JsonProperty("City")]
    public string City {get; set;}
    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public double Population {get; set;}
    [JsonIgnore]
    public double Latitude {get; set;}
    [JsonIgnore]
    public double Longitude {get; set;}
    public double[] Location 
    {
        get { return new double[] { Latitude, Longitude }; }
    }
}
```

Although the custom `JsonConverter`, may be a cleaner solution.